# Completion time of autonomous navigator of ROS

Tags: navigation, odometry, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Can autonomous navigator of ROS give **two different completion time** for **two experiments in the same environment** and ***having same starting and ending positions***?
2. Are the **default recovery behavior of move_base node** for two experiments will be **exactly same?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194871/completion-time-of-autonomous-navigator-of-ros./) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-10-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1 Yes. There are no guarantees on that and I'd actually assume that you will not get the same results. First, I think you'd obviously talk about simulation and not real robots. But even then and if the simulation is running without any noise we don't have a round based system, where data is passed on synchronously. For example, a single laser scan might not arrive in the same time window between runs leading to a slightly different costmap and thus behaviour. This is even excluding the fact that algorithms might do random sampling. This will affect everything happening after that as it depends on each other.

That being said. We are talking about **exactly** the same. Depending on the stability of the algorithms and simulation you can assume similar values as you would on a real world system.

2 The settings/configuration if you pass them in will be the same. The actually observed behavior will be affected by the same things as 1.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-13**:
DWA (commonly used for local navigation if using the nav stack) is a sampling based planner, so there'd be a major source of  instability right there.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-10-13**:
Note: It is sampled in the sense that it does not find the true optimal trajectory, but samples evenly in a given velocity range. It is not random sampling.